# qt soap client + ASP.net Web service

Tags: c++, asp.net, qt, web-services, soap

I'm writing Qt client for ASP.NET web service with FORMS based authentication.

The service consists of 3 methods:

- `Login(user,pass)`
- `Helloworld()` - this method returns info about authenticated user.
- `Logout()`

Every thing working fine on the dot.net client with `CookieContainer`.

The problem begins with HelloWorld() methods. it returns null because I can't access server session.

I'm doing the following:

from the response of Login() request I'm getting the cookies which are sent to client:

```cs
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = http.networkAccessManager();
cookie = manager->cookieJar();
```

When sending the second soaprequest for HelloWorld method I adding these cookies 
to QtSoapHttpTransport http:

```cs
http.networkAccessManager()->setCookieJar(cookie)
```

but the request which is going from server is empty.

I moved further with my investigation and monitored HTTP traffic coming to server from Qt client and .NET client.

The HTTP Header for both SOAP requests are different:

This is Request coming from .NET client

```xml
POST /test/service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 2.0.50727.3053)
VsDebuggerCausalityData: uIDPoyhZznNkbItPkJSR3EA+zEIAAAAAUkpe7URduE6nmhnT8f uQeqCQBMlX0zxCm65yW4ZPBkUACQAA
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://localhost/test/HelloWorld"
Host: localhost:8080
Cookie: MyAuthenCookie=DC7620DA79E080FECA37AC6866BF2690D57 B37443506F0D7EEA9DF209827360894D80D37E1B121D73EE44 766BDAEE16BA3FB0E8B95ADB1252AB00A76706930ACDC87CF9 F26744B7E9E3EB7FBB3812997
Content-Length: 291
Expect: 100-continue
```

and this is Request coming from Qt SOAP client:

```
POST /test/Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://localhost/test/HelloWorld
Content-Length: 350
Cookie: MyAuthenCookie=9AFB2B22EE78D19DFD52BD2193A3D71627C F7303C15E4354E43CC2F31AECBDFFAD09176AA45F33B35C3C3 73891F1FE994580E8EE70FD4D01507670743138E74E152CFF4 EB3C37D90D3A7A0E272A804C3
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
Host: localhost:8080
```

Does any body have any idea what might be the problem and hoe to solve it?

How can I modify Headers for HTTP POST request in `QtSoapHttpTransport` object in order to make it identical to .NET request?

Thank you in advance,
Danny.

Comment: So, the request from Qt soap client can invoke your HelloWorld webmethod -- the issue is that inside of HelloWorld you can't access the session?

Comment: Yep. Although it seaems like i'm sending SOAP request with correct cookie (you can see it from HTTP header) I still can't access session and retrive information from there. 

Best regards,
Danny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running IIS or the ASP.NET Development server?

I was able to recreate a similar problem where everything worked fine using ASP.NET Development server but under IIS the session was null.

One thing to look for is when you invoke the session-enabled-service you should see the ASP.NET_SessionId being set in the response headers

```
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=5vxqwy45waoqma45lbbozj45; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: MyAuthenCookie=510969D70201B358F8B0BBEEE7E79316B7ABCCC74312B0BD678DA4BE90E5C51CD6E7CDCA486DDB41BCBF489DB7280B3B979FD70B78D7F63B03C33431ADDAFDCA; expires=Mon, 07-Dec-2009 06:41:04 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
```

To get sessions working under IIS, I had to add the following to web.config under system.web:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
<httpModules>
  <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" 
</httpModules>
```

This was under Windows 2003.